# PyDev throws NPE During Sync SystemPYTHONPATH

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, eclipse-rcp, pydev

I have an RCP app built with PYDEV in it, and every time I launch it, if there is one or more interpreters cnfigured, PyDev throws a NullPointerException while running the Sync System PYTHONPATH job. It will do this if I manually check the synchronization by clicking the button on the PyDev/Interpreters preference page, or if PyDev does the automatic sync check within one minute of starting.

It does this if I configure any interpreter. When I configure the same interpreter in the Eclipse IDE itself, I don't get the NPE. So something in my RCP app is causing PyDev to throw this error, but I don't have any idea what else I need to do to use PyDev in the app.

The NPE occurs at SynchSystemModulesManager lie 391, using PyDev 4.2.0

Comment: At line 391 of SynchSystemModulesManager, builder is null. It was pased in as null and assigned with a call to ExtensionHelper.getParticipant() in line 378, and returned null from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builder that was supposed to be contributed via an extension point was null. This led me to realize that I was missing some required plugins in the eclipse run config and in the Maven build. The problem was solved by making sure that all dependencies of org.python.pydev were included in the product.

Comment: This issues occurred when I updated my Eclipse from Juno to Mars. Installing the PyDev plugin again fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to implement the required extension, it does not have to do anything.

Add the extension to your plugin.xml:

```
<extension
     point="org.python.pydev.pydev_interpreter_info_builder">
  <interpreter_info_builder_participant
        class="org.example.InterpreterInfoBuilderParticipant">
  </interpreter_info_builder_participant>
```

Then add the class:

```
public class InterpreterInfoBuilderParticipant implements IInterpreterInfoBuilder {
    @Override
    public BuilderResult syncInfoToPythonPath(IProgressMonitor arg0, InterpreterInfo arg1) {
        // Do nothing
        return null;
    }
}
```